# ProxyPassMatch not working in apache2 and ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, proxy

So i proxied a page (on server abc so that xyz would be the proxy):

```
ProxyPass /activation http://xyz.com:88/activation
ProxyPassReverse /activation http://xyz.com:88/activation
```

So when you load xyz page on server abc, abc is displayed in address bar.

Problem is all the css, javascript, and images need for page are not proxied, so browser shows this:

```
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/addclear.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/jquery.truncate.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/jquery.min.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.staticvoid.info/toggleEdit/toggleEdit.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/jquery.dateFormat-1.0.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/rails.validations.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/rails.validations.custom.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/application/initializers.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/jquery.multiselect.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/application/toolbox.events.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/stylesheets/formtastic.css?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/stylesheets/formtastic_changes.css?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/stylesheets/jquery.multiselect.css?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/stylesheets/jquery.tooltip.css?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/themes/abc/stylesheets/abc.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/themes/abc/stylesheets/reset.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/application.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/themes/abc/stylesheets/login.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/stylesheets/application.css?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/themes/abc/stylesheets/style.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/themes/abc/images/callnow.jpg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/themes/abc/images/eagletrackgps.jpg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/themes/abc/images/madeinamerica.jpg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/images/btn-abc.jpg?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/images/btn-abc.jpg?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/images/btn-abc.jpg?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/images/btn-abc.jpg?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
GET http://abc.com/stylesheets/blueprint/print.css?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
```

So I tried ProxyPassMatch directive:

```
ProxyPassMatch /^(javascripts|stylesheets)$/^(.*)$  http://xyz.com:88/$1/$2
```

But it didnt work. That above directive should have removed this error, for example:

```
GET http://abc.com/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1330619664 404 (Not Found)
```

After all, that above request matches the url pattern match.

thanks for response

UPDATE:: Got it working when I fixed the regex:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(javascripts|stylesheets)/(.*)$ http://abc.com:88/$1/$2
```

Comment: Look at ProxyPassMatch (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) if you want to use regex.

Comment: I notice with proxypassmatch that the regex is always on left side, but i assume its ok if i put regex on right side.

Comment: If you mean something like  `ProxyPassMatch /activation(.*) http://abc.com:88/activation$1` then yes -- notice the regex operators `(.*)` on the left and the corresponding `$1` on the right.

Comment: I mean something like this:  ProxyPassMatch /activation http://abc.com:88/^(activation|\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.js|\.css)$

Comment: In my example, the regex is on the right side because if user is on server a then when we proxy server b i want to make sure that not only activation page on server b is proxied but all js, css, and image files on server b are proxied as well.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. What you want to match is on the left, and if you want to use it on the right, you can use `$1` for 1st match, `$2` for the 2nd match and so on.

Comment: I updated my question. I tried your suggestion but when restarting apache, it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With KM01 recommendation to use proxypassmatch, I resolved this issue:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(javascripts|stylesheets)/(.*)$ http://abc.com:88/$1/$2
```